# How to write html text into text-area in robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, ui-automation

I want to add the following code into a textarea input, how should I do this using Robot Framework?

```
<table style="margin-top: 1em; margin-left:1em;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="/static/31bc33ac/images/48x48/orange-square.png" style="width: 48px; height: 48px; " class="icon-orange-square icon-xlg"></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                <p><span>Started by user <a href="/user/vkatkar">Vaishali Katkar</a></span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="/static/31bc33ac/plugin/metrics/images/48x48/clock.png" alt="" style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin-right:1em;"></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                <p>This run spent 1 sec waiting in the queue.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="/static/31bc33ac/plugin/git/icons/git-48x48.png" alt="" style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin-right:1em;"></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle"><b>Revision</b>: 861b6af99e7899d0b725459417e9fadfa25e2706
                <ul>
                    <li>develop</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML string contains many characters that should normally be escaped. For this reason it's easier to load it from a regular text file into a variable and then output that variable into the desired textarea element.

In the below example this being done using an example site:

**FillInForm.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    Selenium2Library

Test Setup        Start Browser
Test Teardown     Close Browser
Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers


*** Test Cases ***
Fill Textarea with HTML code
    ${file_contents}    Get File    ./htmlcode.txt
    Input Text    name=longtext     ${file_contents}
    Sleep    3s

*** Keywords ***
Start Browser
    Open Browser    http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms08.htm    Chrome
```

**htmlcode.txt**

```
Contains the HTML code you want to insert.
```